# Apply style to multiple iOS layers at once

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have many buttons that I am applying the same style to.  Is it possible to apply the style to all of the buttons in an easier way than how I am doing it below?  Perhaps something with a loop that will update all of the layers in just a few lines of code?

```
[_Level1.layer setCornerRadius:17.0f];
[_Level2.layer setCornerRadius:17.0f];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can indeed use a simple for-loop to achieve that.

```
NSArray *buttons = @[_Level1, _Level2, _Level3];
for (UIButton *level in buttons) {
    [level.layer setCornerRadius:17.0f];
    // other setup you need to do...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A one line solution:

```
[@[_Level1, _Level2, _Level3] setValue:@(17.0f) forKeyPath:@"layer.cornerRadius"]
```